# Adding to a specified List within a matrix of Lists

Tags: java, list, matrix

This is a homework program I"m working on for an algorithms course. The task is to simulate an adjacency matrix for a graph using a matrix of Lists (this is Java btw). The element of the matrix is interpreted as the first node. Any nodes it is connected to in the graph are added to the list of that is that matrix element. I have constructed the matrix as such:

```
List<Node>[] weightedList = new List[size]
```

I understand that there are issues with Lists of Objects and type-checking. I then call a method `initializeList()` to construct the initial structure.

```
protected void initializeList() {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for (int i = 1; i < Tester.size; i++){
            weightedList[i] = list;
        }
    }
```

As I'm processing my input data I need to "construct" the graph based on given node values. My problem lies here, when I call `addEdge()` (effectively, connecting two nodes creates an Edge), the node I am trying to add gets added to every element of the matrix. Here is the method:

```
public static void putEdge(Edge e) {
        Node node1 = e.getVertex1();
        Node node2 = e.getVertex2();
        int dim1 = node1.getNode();
        if (dim1 < Tester.size){
            weightedList[dim1].add(node2);
        }   
    }
```

Is my issue related to the type-checking problems inherent in Lists of Objects or something else? Please advise.

-- *JQK*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the same list instance to all the indices of the array.

You should instantiate each list inside the loop :

```
protected void initializeList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Tester.size; i++){
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        weightedList[i] = list;
    }
}
```

This way, each index in the array will contain a different `ArrayList` instance.

And you probably should iterate from 0, since that's the first index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the problem here of assignment only copying a reference to an object, not the object itself. @Eran's solution shows how to assign a different list to each matrix element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Eran. Your solution was correct. Simple mistake on my part. I cannot upvote yet and I'm not sure how to give you credit for the solution.

My error was the location of the assignment statement in `initializeList()`

This is the correct format provided by @Eran.

```
protected void initializeList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Tester.size; i++){
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        weightedList[i] = list;
    }
}
```